# Laravel collective form

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, forms

I have an array with different value, i need to auto-select default value according to client default (they can change it, if they want), i use javascript, but if i use "NULL" js doesn't update the form, without "NULL" it works but class="form-control" doesn't work

**Blade**

```
{!! Form::select('type', $type_array, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-expanded' => 'false']) !!}
```

**Array Structure**

$type_array = [type_id => type]

**Javascript**

```
$('#type').val(response.type_id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**js**

```
$("#type option[value='"+response.type"']").prop("selected", true);
```

**blade**

```
{!! Form::select('type', $type_array, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-expanded' => 'false', 'id' => 'type']) !!}
```